# Logback prudent and multiple rollovers

Tags: logback

The prudent mode enables multiple JVM writes to one single log file.

If I use a RollingFileAppender with prudent mode, how does Logback knows to do the rollover only once? or sync the rollovers. Does it automagically work or should I worry and tweak my configuration to make sure only one JVM is doing rollovers.

I have extended `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` to enable file uploading to a backup storage and I wanted to know what's the best way to make sure the uploading is only done from one file. I can do it with a property or other logic but wanted to understand if Logback had a mechanism already to decide "who does the rollover".

Comment: As usual, the logback manual has what you need: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling

Comment: thanks for the link, I've been there already. I extended the question to explain why I care about "how" and not only "if"